# E-Tag handling for odatav2 in SAP Cloud SDK VDM

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

*Using LATEST java SAP Cloud Sdk*

We are trying to perform an update to OutboundDelivery in S/4 system. We are using API_OUTBOUND_DELIVERY_SRV version 2 for it. The service requires us to use etag, i.e. it requires us to provide a header - `if-match` with the corresponding value of the etag.

We are using VDM for performing the update and are making use of `com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.namespaces.outbounddeliveryv2.batch.OutboundDeliveryV2ServiceBatch`. Please find the code snippet used for update, below:

```
...
OutboundDeliveryV2ServiceBatch service = // Instantiate service;

List<OutbDeliverItem> itemsToUpdate = new ArrayList<>();

items.add(OutbDeliveryItem.builder()
            .deliveryDocument("some key")
            .deliveryDocumentItem("some key")
            .build());

// Assume more additions to items
...
...
...

OutboundDeliveryV2ServiceBatchChangeSet changeSet = service.beginChangeSet();

items.forEach(changeSet::updateOutbDeliveryItem);

changeSet.endChangeSet();

BatchResponse response = service.execute(someDestination);
...
```

As soon as `service.execute(someDestination)` is executed, the update is not performed on S/4 and the logs on S/4 give following error:

```
The Data Service Request is required to be conditional. Try using the "If-Match" header.
```

My questions:

1. Why does the VDM/SDK not take care of etag handling internally? According to [the section **Optimistic concurrency control** in this blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/04/25/new-versions-of-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-2.15.0-for-java-and-1.1.0-for-javascript/), it is mentioned that it is taken care of automatically in javascript sdk but what about java sdk?
2. Is it possible to pass this header by using VDM somehow? If yes then how?
3. Or do we have to let go of the optimistic concurrency control from our service in S/4?

Please note that we have to use the batch operation itself due to performance reasons.

Comment: As Dennis pointed out below, the SDK should add the "If-Match" header automatically if and only if you fetched the data before and the etags are present there. But without the exact code you are attempting to execute I can't reproduce the error and it will be hard to help you any further.

Comment: I've updated my question with the code snippet, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ETags are missing because the items to be updated are programmatically created in your application using the builder pattern. Therefore, no ETags are present on them when you execute update and the SDK has none available to set the "If-Match" header when building up the request.

The solution is to fetch the items from the server first. This also ensures that you have the latest version of them for the update which is a prerequisite for updating them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @MatKuhr. Actually we have to update a lot of items (_in range of about ~1000 items_). It is not efficient for us to read so much items first due to performance reasons. Also the java SDK doesn't provide batch read functionality via VDM as of now (_correct me if I am wrong_).
In addition to this, does the SDK always require me to read an item first and then update it? Isn't it possible to simply update an item with a given key?

Comment: You can fetch all items by using the `getAllOutbDeliveryItem()` method exposed by the service. This will fetch all of the items with the correct etags. There is no way around fetching first because you need to fetch the latest ETag in order to perform update or delete operations.

Comment: Thank you very much. Combining `getAllOutbDeliveryItem()` with `filter()` on a specific property, I am able to limit the response and get eTags too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm confused with regard to which version of the SAP Cloud SDK you're using. Your mentioning JavaScript in your first question, but `com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana` is a Maven package identifier, i.e. Java. Can you please clarify which version you're using?

Either by, both versions should indeed handle this automatically for you. I'm assuming that you're trying to perform some kind of write request (UPDATE or DELETE) that produces the error message you've posted here. In order to send an eTag with such a request, the current eTag must be known beforehand, of course. Have you fetched the latest state of the entity before performing your write request?

Finally, the JavaScript SDK allows you to ignore version identifiers with the `ignoreVersionIdentifier` method on the respective request builder. Generally this is not recommended of course! So make sure to understand why an eTag is required before deciding whether you can ignore it. Finally, there's also `withCustomHeader` where you can supply your own eTag header if for whatever reason none of the above approaches work for you.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question. We are using latest version of java Cloud SDK. As I've mentioned, we have to use batch version of the service. Can you please mention the API which has to be used?