# Handling of etags in batch request using SAP Cloud SDK

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I am trying to carry out a batch request including a create, update and a delete (all are different salesorders). As per this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60055957/e-tag-handling-for-odatav2-in-sap-cloud-sdk-vdm) which deals with something similar, I have done a get for the items I want to update and delete before I add them to the batch request. I am using the SalesOrder.builder() to prepare the SalesOrder I want to create.

```
 final ErpHttpDestination destination = DestinationAccessor.getDestination(DESTINATION_NAME)
                                    .asHttp().decorate(DefaultErpHttpDestination::new);

                    final SalesOrderItem salesOrderItem1 = SalesOrderItem.builder().material(material)
                                    .requestedQuantityUnit(requestedQuantityUnit).build();

                    final SalesOrder salesOrder1 = SalesOrder.builder().distributionChannel(distributionChannel)
                                    .salesOrderType(salesOrderType).salesOrganization(salesOrganization)
                                    .organizationDivision(organizationDivision).soldToParty(soldToParty)
                                    .item(salesOrderItem1).build();

                    final SalesOrder orderToUpdate = new GetSingleSalesOrderCommand(orderToUpdateID, destination,
                                    new DefaultSalesOrderService()).execute();
                    orderToUpdate.setSoldToParty(updateSoldToParty);

                    final SalesOrder orderToDelete = new GetSingleSalesOrderCommand(orderToDeleteID, destination,
                                    new DefaultSalesOrderService()).execute();

                    SalesOrderServiceBatch service = new DefaultSalesOrderServiceBatch(
                                    new DefaultSalesOrderService());

                    BatchResponse bRes = service.beginChangeSet().createSalesOrder(salesOrder1).updateSalesOrder(orderToUpdate)
                                    .deleteSalesOrder(orderToDelete).endChangeSet().execute(destination);
```

I am then logging the BatchResponse and see I am getting a Batch Response Failure:

```
eTag handling not supported for http method 'POST'
```

I have searched for this error but can't find any resolution to it. Any ideas?
Thanks.

UPDATE: Increasing the logging to DEBUG I can see the batch request that is being sent and can see that there is an if-match header being added to the create request, which doesn't make sense as it can't match something that doesn't exist yet.

```
 "msg":"--batch_123\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; 
 boundary=changeset_(changeset number)\r\n\r\n--
 changeset_(changeset number)\r\nContent-Type: 
 application/http\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\nPOST 
 /sap/opu/odata/sap/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/A_SalesOrder HTTP/1.1\r\nContent- 
 Length:
193\r\nIf-Match: W/\"datetimeoffset'2020-05- 
 01T11%3A51%3A16.8631720Z'\"\r\nAccept: 
 application/json;odata=verbose\r\nContent-Type:......
```

The I get the error:

```
  Inner Error:
 "msg":"batch 
  responseFailure(com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataException: 
  null: <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><error 
  xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata\"> 
  <code>/IWFND/CM_MGW/537</code><message xml:lang=\"en\">eTag handling not 
  supported for http method 'POST'</message><innererror>...
```

However, what does work is if I wrap each request in its own changeset e.g.

```
 service
 .beginChangeSet().createSalesOrder(order).endChangeSet()
 .beginChangeSet().updateSalesOrder(orderToUpdate).endChangeSet()
 .beginChangeSet().deleteSalesOrder(orderToDelete).endChangeSet()
 .execute(destination);
```

Comment: I updated my initial answer to point out that this got fixed with version `3.25.0`

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

This is fixed as of version `3.25.0`.

---

**Initial Answer:**

This seems to be a bug. I was able to reproduce this with a different service and the behaviour is the same: The `if-match` header is incorrectly applied to the POST operation as well.

When debugging it seems like the request is build up correctly with the header only being present on update and delete. However, it seems that when the batch request is serialised to JSON it gets added to all requests.

So until this is fixed the workaround is isolating these operations via change sets, as you already pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like eTag handling is not supported for your endpoint.

Now you can do the following to omit eTag headers:

```
orderToUpdate.setVersionIdentifier(null); 
orderToDelete.setVersionIdentifier(null);
```

However I'm not sure how `'POST'` fits the error description, because *update* uses `PATCH` and *delete* uses `DELETE`. The only `POST` that I expect would be coming from *create*. But we do not add headers for entity version identifiers (eTag) in OData create operation. If the same error still comes up, please try again without running `createSalesOrder(salesOrder1)`.

Comment: Ok, so here's what I have done. I set the versionIdentifiers to null and I get the error - "The Data Service Request is required to be conditional. Try using the "If-Match" header." So then I reinstated them. Then I ran each of the pieces of the changeset individually (create, update, and delete) and they all complete as expected. So it seems to only be when I chain them that I get the error. For example, if I include the create and update I get the message in the original post. If I remove the create I get a message "The document was updated using [Comm Arr]. Action could not be completed"

Comment: Hi Inkers, thanks for testing the requests separately. For further investigation would it be possible to raise the log level to `debug` and post here the request body? I want to make sure that Etag is referenced correctly as in the [specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part1-protocol.html#sec_ReferencinganETag).  In case of Batch is has to be a field in the body, not a header.

Comment: As a quick fix, you may try to read the Entity before updating it. Currently, you update it immediately after creation but reading the specification [Create request](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part1-protocol.html#_Toc31358976) doesn't return E-tag. Or make create first, and then run a batch of `read, update, delete`. You can also post a body from both requests to see if E-tag referencing happens correctly or at all. It will simplify the further investigation and fixing if in case it's an implementation bug.

Comment: Hi Artyom, Thanks for response. Each of the requests is a different salesorder so not updating the one I'm creating. I have added an update to the question above with request body. Thanks.